# How to Split Strings in Textboxes with Delimiters

Tags: vb.net, button, split, textbox, delimiter

I would like clicking the button would like the strings of the first textbox to divide to the others using a delimiter. I don't have idea how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimalistic solution using [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim splitResult as String()

splitResult = textBoxIn.Text.Split(":")
textBoxOut1.Text = splitResult(0)

splitResult = splitResult(1).Split("-")
textBoxOut2.Text = splitResult(0)
textBoxOut3.Text = splitResult(1)
```

`String.Split()` splits first the string from `textBoxIn`(`"Word:Number-Div"`) with `":"` creating an array with `{"Word", "Number-Div"}`. After that the second substring(`"Number-Div"`) is split with `"-"` creating an array with `{"Number", "Div"}`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Could you explain basically how this works?

Comment: Extended ma answer with an short explanation.

Comment: Ooooh' Thank you!